# How do I change the git repo of my Angular2 project?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use ng github-pages:deploy to deploy my site, but it keeps trying to create a new git repo even though I already have the code in a repo.  I don't know how to tell it that the repo already exists and how to use that repo.

Comment: How did you download the project locally via git pull or git clone? Can you push to the repo normally using git add . Then git commit -m "" then git push -u origin master?

Comment: I followed this: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html to get started on my project locally, and then created the repo and pushed everything to there

Comment: That isn't an angular-cli project is it. I'm unsure if  ng github-pages:deploy works properly on none cli projects.

Comment: That's a problem.  I can't seem to find anything online that gives me info on how to deploy with the way I did things.

Comment: Angular-cli to my understanding is to only be used on angular-cli projects. You will see the angular-cli config file in the root of the project. If it isn't you will have to either convert it to be one or do these things manually with git push the correct branch and settings files.